# C++ CRTP initialization

Tags: c++, initialization, crtp

i ran into a segfault running the following program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename Derived>
struct CRTPBase {
  CRTPBase() {
    func();
  }
  void func() {
    static_cast<Derived*>(this)->_func();
  }
};
struct CRTPChild : CRTPBase<CRTPChild>{
  using CRTPBase<CRTPChild>::CRTPBase;
  void _func(){
    vec.resize(10);
    vec[0] = 2;
  }
  std::vector<int> vec;
};
int main()
{
    CRTPChild obj;
    std::cout << obj.vec[0] << std::endl;
}
```

When i replace `vec` with a member of type `int` it doesn't segfault anymore. Why?

Comment: Why are you trying to use a vector before it was constructed? The constructor of the base class is run before the constructor of the derived class, which in turn calls the constructor of vec. Thus, vec was not yet constructed when you start using it.

Comment: @liliscent good point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior. The problem comes from the [order of the initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Initialization_order); for the derived class `CRTPChild`, the constructor of the base class `CRTPBase<CRTPChild>` is invoked firstly, after that the data member `vec` of `CRTPChild` get initialized. When `_func` is invoked (from the constructor of the base class) `vec` is not initialized at all.

> 2) Then, direct base classes are initialized in left-to-right order as
>   they appear in this class's base-specifier list
>
> 3) Then, non-static data members are initialized in order of
>   declaration in the class definition.

Changing the type to `int` it's still [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). UB means anything is possible, it might lead to segfault or might not.

Answer (score 3):

When `CRTPBase` constructor is called, `CRTPChild` is not yet fully constructed, so calling it's member function is undefined behavior.

The way undefined behavior manifests itself depends on platform, compiler and phase of the moon.

In particular, when your member is an int, the fact that it is not yet constructed doesn't cause program to crash when you are using int - there are no invariants for `int`. Vector, on the other hand, has invariants, so accessing unconstructed vector will violate them, and cause incorrect memory access.

Answer (score 2):

The base-class will be initialized (i.e. constructed) before the child class. That means when you call `CRTPChild::_func` the `CRTPChild` part of the object (including the vector) haven't been constructed yet. Using the vector in any way will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Don't access (non-static) members of child-classes in a base-class constructor.