# Can a CRTP Base class constructor access Derived data members

Tags: c++

Given a CRTP Base class

```
template <typename Child>
struct Base 
{
  Base() 
  {  
    static_cast<Child*>(this)->i = 1;  
  }
};
```

and a Derived class

```
struct Derived : Base<Derived> 
{
  int i = 2;
};
```

the following program

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
  Derived d{};
  std::cout << d.i;
}
```

prints `2` on gcc and clang.

Except on gcc since 7.1 in c++17 mode, where it prints `1`.

Is this a bug? Or am I invoking UB? It does seem odd that `Base` is touching a member of `Derived` before it's even had a chance to be constructed. (`-Wall` and `-Wextra` say nothing.)

Also, if I define `Derived` 's constructor

```
struct Derived : Base<Derived> 
{
  int i = 2;
  Derived() {}
};
```

or even declare `Base` 's constructor

```
struct Derived : Base<Derived> 
{
  using Base<Derived>::Base;
  int i = 2;
};
```

both compilers print `2`.

So if this is not UB, how does this work exactly, and print `2`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52724248/c-crtp-initialization this is exactly the same question, code is just different a bit. Yes, it is a UB land.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. Thanks a ton.